# Benchmarking Qt5 and C++17 containers for perfomance and memory usage

Tags: qt, gcc, containers, clang, c++17

I need an up-to-date benchmark of both `Qt5` and `C++17` containers in both performance and heap memory-usage, both on latest `GCC` and `CLang` compilers, for my own project.

The results was helpful for my decisions in the project and I think it might be helpful for others too, so I decided to share it.

So it is a benchmark with these parameters in mind:

- `Qt5` Containers vs `C++17` Containers
- Performance vs Memory Usage
- Container Initialization/Generation Time vs Access/Find/Iteration Time
- `GCC 11` vs `CLang 11`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Benchmark platform:

Hardware:

- CPU: 6-Core AMD 6200
- RAM: 32GB DDRIII

Software:

- OS: OpenSUSE 15.2 x64
- Qt: 15.1 (Official Binary)
- GCC: 11.0.0
- CLang: 11.0.0
- HeapTrack 1.1.0

Standard:

- C++17

Flags

- -O3

Code:

- https://github.com/AshkanV/Qt5vsCpp17ContainerBench

[image]

Comment: can you share the code of the benchmark? For me the numbers are not that useful when I don't know exactly where they come from

Comment: What compile flags were used? Also, it's better to encode graphics as PNG to avoid JPEG artifacts.

Comment: You are right. benchmark without the real code is generally useless:
https://github.com/AshkanV/Qt5vsCpp17ContainerBench

Comment: The image I uploaded was PNG but after the uploading to the stackoverflow, its changed. I think its on purpose and their internal saving algorithm.

Comment: I just set the release option of cmake. but now I also set CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE to true and cmake compile shows: -O3 -DNDEBUG -fPIC -std=gnu++17